# With react native navigation on iOS, how to change the background color of the status bar when the app is in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to change the background colour of the status bar, in iOS, when the app goes in background to let the user know that the app is running in the background.
but no success so far.

My code looks like that:

```
function _handleAppStateChange(nextAppState) {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === "active") {

          Navigation.mergeOptions(component.id, {
              statusBar: {
                  visible: false,
              }
          });

    }else if(this.state.appState.match(/active/) && nextAppState === "inactive"){

          Navigation.mergeOptions(component.id, {
              statusBar: {
                  visible: true,
                  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
              }

          });

    }

    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
};
```

If it is not possible to do it via react-native-navigation, would it be possible with objective-c?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: iOS changes the status bar when your app is performing certain actions in the background. If you have "when in use" location permission but are using background location the bar will be blue, if you are using the microphone or recording the screen it will be red. You can't set the status bar colour directly